# Error: end-of-file after a modification of my Fortran code

Tags: visual-studio, fortran

I am using Fortran code to make it easier to extract the data I need from my many output files. First, I built a code to use with a specific file called 'output.sub' and it works fine to extract the various variables I needed. Now, I tried to use the code with another file 'output.rch' which has a similar structure to the previous one. Changed what needs to be changed to address the new output file, but now I get the end-of-file error. I am using Fixed-Form Fortran file on Visual Studios Professional 2017.

This is the old code:

```
    PROGRAM WATER_BALANCE
IMPLICIT NONE


INTEGER I,J,K
INTEGER FLAGP(516),FLAGS(516),FLAGPET(516),FLAGET(516),
 $  FLAGSW(516),FLAGPER(516),FLAGSUR(516),FLAGGW(516),FLAGWYLD(516)
REAL A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,L
REAL PRECIP(516),SNOMELT(516),PET(516),ET(516),SW(516),PERC(516),
 $SURQ(516),GW_Q(516),WYLD(516)
REAL PETB(14,516)  !1999,2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012

DO I=1,516
    PRECIP(I)=0.0
    SNOMELT(I)=0.0
    PET(I)=0.0
    ET(I)=0.0
    SW(I)=0.0
    PERC(I)=0.0
    SURQ(I)=0.0
    GW_Q(I)=0.0
    WYLD(I)=0.0
END DO



OPEN(1,FILE='output.sub',STATUS='OLD')

DO I=1,9
READ(1,*)
END DO



DO I=1,365   !1999Äê
    DO J=1,516
        READ(1,"(41X,9E10.3)") A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,L
        PRECIP(J)=PRECIP(J)+A
        SNOMELT(J)=SNOMELT(J)+B
        PET(J)=PET(J)+C
        ET(J)=ET(J)+D
        SW(J)=SW(J)+E
        PERC(J)=PERC(J)+F
        SURQ(J)=SURQ(J)+G
        GW_Q(J)=GW_Q(J)+H
        WYLD(J)=WYLD(J)+L
    END DO
END DO

DO K=1,516
    PETB(1,K)=PET(K)/365
    PET(K)=0.0
  END DO


  DO I=366,731   !2000
    DO J=1,516
        READ(1,"(41X,9E10.3)") A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,L
        PRECIP(J)=PRECIP(J)+A
        SNOMELT(J)=SNOMELT(J)+B
        PET(J)=PET(J)+C
        ET(J)=ET(J)+D
        SW(J)=SW(J)+E
        PERC(J)=PERC(J)+F
        SURQ(J)=SURQ(J)+G
        GW_Q(J)=GW_Q(J)+H
        WYLD(J)=WYLD(J)+L
    END DO
  END DO


DO K=1,516
    PETB(2,K)=PET(K)/366
    PET(K)=0.0
  END DO

  DO I=732,1096   !2001
    DO J=1,516
        READ(1,"(41X,9E10.3)") A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,L
        PRECIP(J)=PRECIP(J)+A
        SNOMELT(J)=SNOMELT(J)+B
        PET(J)=PET(J)+C
        ET(J)=ET(J)+D
        SW(J)=SW(J)+E
        PERC(J)=PERC(J)+F
        SURQ(J)=SURQ(J)+G
        GW_Q(J)=GW_Q(J)+H
        WYLD(J)=WYLD(J)+L
    END DO
END DO

DO K=1,516
    PETB(3,K)=PET(K)/366
    PET(K)=0.0
  END DO



  DO I=1097,1461   !2002
    DO J=1,516
        READ(1,"(41X,9E10.3)") A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,L
        PRECIP(J)=PRECIP(J)+A
        SNOMELT(J)=SNOMELT(J)+B
        PET(J)=PET(J)+C
        ET(J)=ET(J)+D
        SW(J)=SW(J)+E
        PERC(J)=PERC(J)+F
        SURQ(J)=SURQ(J)+G
        GW_Q(J)=GW_Q(J)+H
        WYLD(J)=WYLD(J)+L
    END DO
END DO

DO K=1,516
    PETB(4,K)=PET(K)/366
    PET(K)=0.0
  END DO



  DO I=1462,1826   !2003
    DO J=1,516
        READ(1,"(41X,9E10.3)") A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,L
        PRECIP(J)=PRECIP(J)+A
        SNOMELT(J)=SNOMELT(J)+B
        PET(J)=PET(J)+C
        ET(J)=ET(J)+D
        SW(J)=SW(J)+E
        PERC(J)=PERC(J)+F
        SURQ(J)=SURQ(J)+G
        GW_Q(J)=GW_Q(J)+H
        WYLD(J)=WYLD(J)+L
    END DO
END DO

DO K=1,516
    PETB(5,K)=PET(K)/366
    PET(K)=0.0
  END DO


  DO I=1827,2191   !2004
    DO J=1,516
        READ(1,"(41X,9E10.3)") A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,L
        PRECIP(J)=PRECIP(J)+A
        SNOMELT(J)=SNOMELT(J)+B
        PET(J)=PET(J)+C
        ET(J)=ET(J)+D
        SW(J)=SW(J)+E
        PERC(J)=PERC(J)+F
        SURQ(J)=SURQ(J)+G
        GW_Q(J)=GW_Q(J)+H
        WYLD(J)=WYLD(J)+L
    END DO
END DO

DO K=1,516
    PETB(6,K)=PET(K)/366
    PET(K)=0.0
  END DO


  DO I=2192,2556   !2005
    DO J=1,516
        READ(1,"(41X,9E10.3)") A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,L
        PRECIP(J)=PRECIP(J)+A
        SNOMELT(J)=SNOMELT(J)+B
        PET(J)=PET(J)+C
        ET(J)=ET(J)+D
        SW(J)=SW(J)+E
        PERC(J)=PERC(J)+F
        SURQ(J)=SURQ(J)+G
        GW_Q(J)=GW_Q(J)+H
        WYLD(J)=WYLD(J)+L
    END DO
END DO

DO K=1,516
    PETB(7,K)=PET(K)/366
    PET(K)=0.0
  END DO



  DO I=2557,2921   !2006
    DO J=1,516
        READ(1,"(41X,9E10.3)") A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,L
        PRECIP(J)=PRECIP(J)+A
        SNOMELT(J)=SNOMELT(J)+B
        PET(J)=PET(J)+C
        ET(J)=ET(J)+D
        SW(J)=SW(J)+E
        PERC(J)=PERC(J)+F
        SURQ(J)=SURQ(J)+G
        GW_Q(J)=GW_Q(J)+H
        WYLD(J)=WYLD(J)+L
    END DO
END DO

DO K=1,516
    PETB(8,K)=PET(K)/366
    PET(K)=0.0
  END DO


  DO I=2922,3287   !2007
    DO J=1,516
        READ(1,"(41X,9E10.3)") A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,L
        PRECIP(J)=PRECIP(J)+A
        SNOMELT(J)=SNOMELT(J)+B
        PET(J)=PET(J)+C
        ET(J)=ET(J)+D
        SW(J)=SW(J)+E
        PERC(J)=PERC(J)+F
        SURQ(J)=SURQ(J)+G
        GW_Q(J)=GW_Q(J)+H
        WYLD(J)=WYLD(J)+L
    END DO
END DO

DO K=1,516
    PETB(9,K)=PET(K)/366
    PET(K)=0.0
  END DO


DO I=3288,3653   !2008
    DO J=1,516
        READ(1,"(41X,9E10.3)") A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,L
        PRECIP(J)=PRECIP(J)+A
        SNOMELT(J)=SNOMELT(J)+B
        PET(J)=PET(J)+C
        ET(J)=ET(J)+D
        SW(J)=SW(J)+E
        PERC(J)=PERC(J)+F
        SURQ(J)=SURQ(J)+G
        GW_Q(J)=GW_Q(J)+H
        WYLD(J)=WYLD(J)+L
    END DO
END DO

DO K=1,516
    PETB(10,K)=PET(K)/366
    PET(K)=0.0
  END DO


  DO I=3654,4018   !2009
    DO J=1,516
        READ(1,"(41X,9E10.3)") A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,L
        PRECIP(J)=PRECIP(J)+A
        SNOMELT(J)=SNOMELT(J)+B
        PET(J)=PET(J)+C
        ET(J)=ET(J)+D
        SW(J)=SW(J)+E
        PERC(J)=PERC(J)+F
        SURQ(J)=SURQ(J)+G
        GW_Q(J)=GW_Q(J)+H
        WYLD(J)=WYLD(J)+L
    END DO
END DO

DO K=1,516
    PETB(11,K)=PET(K)/366
    PET(K)=0.0
  END DO


  DO I=4019,4383   !2010
    DO J=1,516
        READ(1,"(41X,9E10.3)") A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,L
        PRECIP(J)=PRECIP(J)+A
        SNOMELT(J)=SNOMELT(J)+B
        PET(J)=PET(J)+C
        ET(J)=ET(J)+D
        SW(J)=SW(J)+E
        PERC(J)=PERC(J)+F
        SURQ(J)=SURQ(J)+G
        GW_Q(J)=GW_Q(J)+H
        WYLD(J)=WYLD(J)+L
    END DO
END DO

DO K=1,516
    PETB(12,K)=PET(K)/366
    PET(K)=0.0
  END DO


  DO I=4384,4748   !2011
    DO J=1,516
        READ(1,"(41X,9E10.3)") A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,L
        PRECIP(J)=PRECIP(J)+A
        SNOMELT(J)=SNOMELT(J)+B
        PET(J)=PET(J)+C
        ET(J)=ET(J)+D
        SW(J)=SW(J)+E
        PERC(J)=PERC(J)+F
        SURQ(J)=SURQ(J)+G
        GW_Q(J)=GW_Q(J)+H
        WYLD(J)=WYLD(J)+L
    END DO
END DO

DO K=1,516
    PETB(13,K)=PET(K)/366
    PET(K)=0.0
END DO


DO I=4749,5114   !2012
    DO J=1,516
        READ(1,"(41X,9E10.3)") A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,L
        PRECIP(J)=PRECIP(J)+A
        SNOMELT(J)=SNOMELT(J)+B
        PET(J)=PET(J)+C
        ET(J)=ET(J)+D
        SW(J)=SW(J)+E
        PERC(J)=PERC(J)+F
        SURQ(J)=SURQ(J)+G
        GW_Q(J)=GW_Q(J)+H
        WYLD(J)=WYLD(J)+L
    END DO
END DO

DO K=1,516
    PETB(14,K)=PET(K)/366
    PET(K)=0.0
END DO



OPEN(2,FILE='OUT',STATUS='UNKNOWN')
    DO K=1,516
        WRITE(2,"(14(E10.3,5X))") PETB(1,K),PETB(2,K),PETB(3,K),PETB(4,K),
 $        PETB(5,K),PETB(6,K),PETB(7,K),PETB(8,K),PETB(9,K),
 $        PETB(10,K),PETB(11,K),PETB(12,K),PETB(13,K),PETB(14,K)
    END DO

CLOSE(1)
CLOSE(2)
END
```

**UPDATED:** And this is the modified code to use with 'output.rch' file:

```
    PROGRAM WATER_QUALITY
IMPLICIT NONE


INTEGER X,Y,Z
INTEGER FLAGFIN(516),FLAGFOUT(516),FLAGEVAP(516),FLAGTLOSS(516),
 $  FLAGSIN(516),FLAGSOUT(516),FLAGSED(516),FLAGONIN(516),
 $  FLAGONOUT(516), FLAGPIN(516),FLAGPOUT(516),FLAGNO3IN(516),
 $  FLAGNO3OUT(516), FLAGNH4IN(516),FLAGNH4OUT(516),FLAGNO2IN(516),
 $  FLAGNO2OUT(516)
REAL A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q
REAL FLOW_IN(516),FLOW_OUT(516),EVAP(516),TLOSS(516),SED_IN(516),
 $SED_OUT(516),SEDCONC(516),ORGN_IN(516),ORGN_OUT(516),ORGP_IN(516),
 $ORGP_OUT(516),NO3_IN(516),NO3_OUT(516),NH4_IN(516),NH4_OUT(516),
 $NO2_IN(516),NO2_OUT(516)

  REAL NO3_INB(15,516)  !1999,2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013

DO X=1,516
    FLOW_IN(X)=0.0
    FLOW_OUT(X)=0.0
    EVAP(X)=0.0
    TLOSS(X)=0.0
      SED_IN(X)=0.0
      SED_OUT(X)=0.0
      SEDCONC(X)=0.0
      ORGN_IN(X)=0.0
      ORGN_OUT(X)=0.0
      ORGP_IN(X)=0.0
      ORGP_OUT(X)=0.0
      NO3_IN(X)=0.0
      NO3_OUT(X)=0.0
      NH4_IN(X)=0.0
      NH4_OUT(X)=0.0
      NO2_IN(X)=0.0
      NO2_OUT(X)=0.0
END DO



OPEN(10,FILE='output.rch',STATUS='OLD')

DO X=1,9
READ(10,*)
END DO



DO X=1,365   !1999
    DO Y=1,516
        READ(10,"(44X,17E10.3)")A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q
        FLOW_IN(Y)=FLOW_IN(Y)+A
        FLOW_OUT(Y)=FLOW_OUT(Y)+B
          EVAP(Y)=EVAP(Y)+C
          TLOSS(Y)=TLOSS(Y)+D
          SED_IN(Y)=SED_IN(Y)+E
          SED_OUT(Y)=SED_OUT(Y)+F
          SEDCONC(Y)=SEDCONC(Y)+G
          ORGN_IN(Y)=ORGN_IN(Y)+H
          ORGN_OUT(Y)=ORGN_OUT(Y)+I
          ORGP_IN(Y)=ORGP_IN(Y)+J
          ORGP_OUT(Y)=ORGP_OUT(Y)+K
          NO3_IN(Y)=NO3_IN(Y)+L
          NO3_OUT(Y)=NO3_OUT(Y)+M
          NH4_IN(Y)=NH4_IN(Y)+N
          NH4_OUT(Y)=NH4_OUT(Y)+O
          NO2_IN(Y)=NO2_IN(Y)+P
          NO2_OUT(Y)=NO2_OUT(Y)+Q

    END DO
END DO

DO Z=1,516
    NO3_INB(1,Z)=NO3_IN(Z)/365
    NO3_IN(Z)=0.0
  END DO


  DO X=366,731   !2000
    DO Y=1,516
        READ(10,"(44X,17E10.3)")A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q
        FLOW_IN(Y)=FLOW_IN(Y)+A
        FLOW_OUT(Y)=FLOW_OUT(Y)+B
          EVAP(Y)=EVAP(Y)+C
          TLOSS(Y)=TLOSS(Y)+D
          SED_IN(Y)=SED_IN(Y)+E
          SED_OUT(Y)=SED_OUT(Y)+F
          SEDCONC(Y)=SEDCONC(Y)+G
          ORGN_IN(Y)=ORGN_IN(Y)+H
          ORGN_OUT(Y)=ORGN_OUT(Y)+I
          ORGP_IN(Y)=ORGP_IN(Y)+J
          ORGP_OUT(Y)=ORGP_OUT(Y)+K
          NO3_IN(Y)=NO3_IN(Y)+L
          NO3_OUT(Y)=NO3_OUT(Y)+M
          NH4_IN(Y)=NH4_IN(Y)+N
          NH4_OUT(Y)=NH4_OUT(Y)+O
          NO2_IN(Y)=NO2_IN(Y)+P
          NO2_OUT(Y)=NO2_OUT(Y)+Q

    END DO
END DO

DO Z=1,516
    NO3_INB(2,Z)=NO3_IN(Z)/366
    NO3_IN(Z)=0.0
  END DO

  DO X=732,1096   !2001
    DO Y=1,516
        READ(10,"(44X,17E10.3)")A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q
        FLOW_IN(Y)=FLOW_IN(Y)+A
        FLOW_OUT(Y)=FLOW_OUT(Y)+B
          EVAP(Y)=EVAP(Y)+C
          TLOSS(Y)=TLOSS(Y)+D
          SED_IN(Y)=SED_IN(Y)+E
          SED_OUT(Y)=SED_OUT(Y)+F
          SEDCONC(Y)=SEDCONC(Y)+G
          ORGN_IN(Y)=ORGN_IN(Y)+H
          ORGN_OUT(Y)=ORGN_OUT(Y)+I
          ORGP_IN(Y)=ORGP_IN(Y)+J
          ORGP_OUT(Y)=ORGP_OUT(Y)+K
          NO3_IN(Y)=NO3_IN(Y)+L
          NO3_OUT(Y)=NO3_OUT(Y)+M
          NH4_IN(Y)=NH4_IN(Y)+N
          NH4_OUT(Y)=NH4_OUT(Y)+O
          NO2_IN(Y)=NO2_IN(Y)+P
          NO2_OUT(Y)=NO2_OUT(Y)+Q

    END DO
END DO

DO Z=1,516
    NO3_INB(3,Z)=NO3_IN(Z)/366
    NO3_IN(Z)=0.0
  END DO



  DO X=1097,1461   !2002
    DO Y=1,516
        READ(10,"(44X,17E10.3)")A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q
        FLOW_IN(Y)=FLOW_IN(Y)+A
        FLOW_OUT(Y)=FLOW_OUT(Y)+B
          EVAP(Y)=EVAP(Y)+C
          TLOSS(Y)=TLOSS(Y)+D
          SED_IN(Y)=SED_IN(Y)+E
          SED_OUT(Y)=SED_OUT(Y)+F
          SEDCONC(Y)=SEDCONC(Y)+G
          ORGN_IN(Y)=ORGN_IN(Y)+H
          ORGN_OUT(Y)=ORGN_OUT(Y)+I
          ORGP_IN(Y)=ORGP_IN(Y)+J
          ORGP_OUT(Y)=ORGP_OUT(Y)+K
          NO3_IN(Y)=NO3_IN(Y)+L
          NO3_OUT(Y)=NO3_OUT(Y)+M
          NH4_IN(Y)=NH4_IN(Y)+N
          NH4_OUT(Y)=NH4_OUT(Y)+O
          NO2_IN(Y)=NO2_IN(Y)+P
          NO2_OUT(Y)=NO2_OUT(Y)+Q

    END DO
END DO

DO Z=1,516
    NO3_INB(4,Z)=NO3_IN(Z)/366
    NO3_IN(Z)=0.0
  END DO



  DO X=1462,1826   !2003
    DO Y=1,516
        READ(10,"(44X,17E10.3)")A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q
        FLOW_IN(Y)=FLOW_IN(Y)+A
        FLOW_OUT(Y)=FLOW_OUT(Y)+B
          EVAP(Y)=EVAP(Y)+C
          TLOSS(Y)=TLOSS(Y)+D
          SED_IN(Y)=SED_IN(Y)+E
          SED_OUT(Y)=SED_OUT(Y)+F
          SEDCONC(Y)=SEDCONC(Y)+G
          ORGN_IN(Y)=ORGN_IN(Y)+H
          ORGN_OUT(Y)=ORGN_OUT(Y)+I
          ORGP_IN(Y)=ORGP_IN(Y)+J
          ORGP_OUT(Y)=ORGP_OUT(Y)+K
          NO3_IN(Y)=NO3_IN(Y)+L
          NO3_OUT(Y)=NO3_OUT(Y)+M
          NH4_IN(Y)=NH4_IN(Y)+N
          NH4_OUT(Y)=NH4_OUT(Y)+O
          NO2_IN(Y)=NO2_IN(Y)+P
          NO2_OUT(Y)=NO2_OUT(Y)+Q

    END DO
END DO

DO Z=1,516
    NO3_INB(5,Z)=NO3_IN(Z)/366
    NO3_IN(Z)=0.0
  END DO


  DO X=1827,2191   !2004
    DO Y=1,516
        READ(10,"(44X,17E10.3)")A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q
        FLOW_IN(Y)=FLOW_IN(Y)+A
        FLOW_OUT(Y)=FLOW_OUT(Y)+B
          EVAP(Y)=EVAP(Y)+C
          TLOSS(Y)=TLOSS(Y)+D
          SED_IN(Y)=SED_IN(Y)+E
          SED_OUT(Y)=SED_OUT(Y)+F
          SEDCONC(Y)=SEDCONC(Y)+G
          ORGN_IN(Y)=ORGN_IN(Y)+H
          ORGN_OUT(Y)=ORGN_OUT(Y)+I
          ORGP_IN(Y)=ORGP_IN(Y)+J
          ORGP_OUT(Y)=ORGP_OUT(Y)+K
          NO3_IN(Y)=NO3_IN(Y)+L
          NO3_OUT(Y)=NO3_OUT(Y)+M
          NH4_IN(Y)=NH4_IN(Y)+N
          NH4_OUT(Y)=NH4_OUT(Y)+O
          NO2_IN(Y)=NO2_IN(Y)+P
          NO2_OUT(Y)=NO2_OUT(Y)+Q

    END DO
END DO

DO Z=1,516
    NO3_INB(6,Z)=NO3_IN(Z)/366
    NO3_IN(Z)=0.0
  END DO


  DO X=2192,2556   !2005
    DO Y=1,516
        READ(10,"(44X,17E10.3)")A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q
        FLOW_IN(Y)=FLOW_IN(Y)+A
        FLOW_OUT(Y)=FLOW_OUT(Y)+B
          EVAP(Y)=EVAP(Y)+C
          TLOSS(Y)=TLOSS(Y)+D
          SED_IN(Y)=SED_IN(Y)+E
          SED_OUT(Y)=SED_OUT(Y)+F
          SEDCONC(Y)=SEDCONC(Y)+G
          ORGN_IN(Y)=ORGN_IN(Y)+H
          ORGN_OUT(Y)=ORGN_OUT(Y)+I
          ORGP_IN(Y)=ORGP_IN(Y)+J
          ORGP_OUT(Y)=ORGP_OUT(Y)+K
          NO3_IN(Y)=NO3_IN(Y)+L
          NO3_OUT(Y)=NO3_OUT(Y)+M
          NH4_IN(Y)=NH4_IN(Y)+N
          NH4_OUT(Y)=NH4_OUT(Y)+O
          NO2_IN(Y)=NO2_IN(Y)+P
          NO2_OUT(Y)=NO2_OUT(Y)+Q

    END DO
END DO

DO Z=1,516
    NO3_INB(7,Z)=NO3_IN(Z)/366
    NO3_IN(Z)=0.0
  END DO



  DO X=2557,2921   !2006
    DO Y=1,516
        READ(10,"(44X,17E10.3)")A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q
        FLOW_IN(Y)=FLOW_IN(Y)+A
        FLOW_OUT(Y)=FLOW_OUT(Y)+B
          EVAP(Y)=EVAP(Y)+C
          TLOSS(Y)=TLOSS(Y)+D
          SED_IN(Y)=SED_IN(Y)+E
          SED_OUT(Y)=SED_OUT(Y)+F
          SEDCONC(Y)=SEDCONC(Y)+G
          ORGN_IN(Y)=ORGN_IN(Y)+H
          ORGN_OUT(Y)=ORGN_OUT(Y)+I
          ORGP_IN(Y)=ORGP_IN(Y)+J
          ORGP_OUT(Y)=ORGP_OUT(Y)+K
          NO3_IN(Y)=NO3_IN(Y)+L
          NO3_OUT(Y)=NO3_OUT(Y)+M
          NH4_IN(Y)=NH4_IN(Y)+N
          NH4_OUT(Y)=NH4_OUT(Y)+O
          NO2_IN(Y)=NO2_IN(Y)+P
          NO2_OUT(Y)=NO2_OUT(Y)+Q

    END DO
END DO

DO Z=1,516
    NO3_INB(8,Z)=NO3_IN(Z)/366
    NO3_IN(Z)=0.0
  END DO


  DO X=2922,3287   !2007
    DO Y=1,516
        READ(10,"(44X,17E10.3)")A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q
        FLOW_IN(Y)=FLOW_IN(Y)+A
        FLOW_OUT(Y)=FLOW_OUT(Y)+B
          EVAP(Y)=EVAP(Y)+C
          TLOSS(Y)=TLOSS(Y)+D
          SED_IN(Y)=SED_IN(Y)+E
          SED_OUT(Y)=SED_OUT(Y)+F
          SEDCONC(Y)=SEDCONC(Y)+G
          ORGN_IN(Y)=ORGN_IN(Y)+H
          ORGN_OUT(Y)=ORGN_OUT(Y)+I
          ORGP_IN(Y)=ORGP_IN(Y)+J
          ORGP_OUT(Y)=ORGP_OUT(Y)+K
          NO3_IN(Y)=NO3_IN(Y)+L
          NO3_OUT(Y)=NO3_OUT(Y)+M
          NH4_IN(Y)=NH4_IN(Y)+N
          NH4_OUT(Y)=NH4_OUT(Y)+O
          NO2_IN(Y)=NO2_IN(Y)+P
          NO2_OUT(Y)=NO2_OUT(Y)+Q

    END DO
END DO

DO Z=1,516
    NO3_INB(9,Z)=NO3_IN(Z)/366
    NO3_IN(Z)=0.0
  END DO


DO X=3288,3653   !2008
    DO Y=1,516
        READ(10,"(44X,17E10.3)")A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q
        FLOW_IN(Y)=FLOW_IN(Y)+A
        FLOW_OUT(Y)=FLOW_OUT(Y)+B
          EVAP(Y)=EVAP(Y)+C
          TLOSS(Y)=TLOSS(Y)+D
          SED_IN(Y)=SED_IN(Y)+E
          SED_OUT(Y)=SED_OUT(Y)+F
          SEDCONC(Y)=SEDCONC(Y)+G
          ORGN_IN(Y)=ORGN_IN(Y)+H
          ORGN_OUT(Y)=ORGN_OUT(Y)+I
          ORGP_IN(Y)=ORGP_IN(Y)+J
          ORGP_OUT(Y)=ORGP_OUT(Y)+K
          NO3_IN(Y)=NO3_IN(Y)+L
          NO3_OUT(Y)=NO3_OUT(Y)+M
          NH4_IN(Y)=NH4_IN(Y)+N
          NH4_OUT(Y)=NH4_OUT(Y)+O
          NO2_IN(Y)=NO2_IN(Y)+P
          NO2_OUT(Y)=NO2_OUT(Y)+Q

    END DO
END DO

DO Z=1,516
    NO3_INB(10,Z)=NO3_IN(Z)/366
    NO3_IN(Z)=0.0
  END DO


  DO X=3654,4018   !2009
    DO Y=1,516
        READ(10,"(44X,17E10.3)")A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q
        FLOW_IN(Y)=FLOW_IN(Y)+A
        FLOW_OUT(Y)=FLOW_OUT(Y)+B
          EVAP(Y)=EVAP(Y)+C
          TLOSS(Y)=TLOSS(Y)+D
          SED_IN(Y)=SED_IN(Y)+E
          SED_OUT(Y)=SED_OUT(Y)+F
          SEDCONC(Y)=SEDCONC(Y)+G
          ORGN_IN(Y)=ORGN_IN(Y)+H
          ORGN_OUT(Y)=ORGN_OUT(Y)+I
          ORGP_IN(Y)=ORGP_IN(Y)+J
          ORGP_OUT(Y)=ORGP_OUT(Y)+K
          NO3_IN(Y)=NO3_IN(Y)+L
          NO3_OUT(Y)=NO3_OUT(Y)+M
          NH4_IN(Y)=NH4_IN(Y)+N
          NH4_OUT(Y)=NH4_OUT(Y)+O
          NO2_IN(Y)=NO2_IN(Y)+P
          NO2_OUT(Y)=NO2_OUT(Y)+Q

    END DO
END DO

DO Z=1,516
    NO3_INB(11,Z)=NO3_IN(Z)/366
    NO3_IN(Z)=0.0
  END DO


  DO X=4019,4383   !2010
    DO Y=1,516
        READ(10,"(44X,17E10.3)")A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q
        FLOW_IN(Y)=FLOW_IN(Y)+A
        FLOW_OUT(Y)=FLOW_OUT(Y)+B
          EVAP(Y)=EVAP(Y)+C
          TLOSS(Y)=TLOSS(Y)+D
          SED_IN(Y)=SED_IN(Y)+E
          SED_OUT(Y)=SED_OUT(Y)+F
          SEDCONC(Y)=SEDCONC(Y)+G
          ORGN_IN(Y)=ORGN_IN(Y)+H
          ORGN_OUT(Y)=ORGN_OUT(Y)+I
          ORGP_IN(Y)=ORGP_IN(Y)+J
          ORGP_OUT(Y)=ORGP_OUT(Y)+K
          NO3_IN(Y)=NO3_IN(Y)+L
          NO3_OUT(Y)=NO3_OUT(Y)+M
          NH4_IN(Y)=NH4_IN(Y)+N
          NH4_OUT(Y)=NH4_OUT(Y)+O
          NO2_IN(Y)=NO2_IN(Y)+P
          NO2_OUT(Y)=NO2_OUT(Y)+Q

    END DO
END DO

DO Z=1,516
    NO3_INB(12,Z)=NO3_IN(Z)/366
    NO3_IN(Z)=0.0
  END DO


  DO X=4384,4748   !2011
    DO Y=1,516
        READ(10,"(44X,17E10.3)")A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q
        FLOW_IN(Y)=FLOW_IN(Y)+A
        FLOW_OUT(Y)=FLOW_OUT(Y)+B
          EVAP(Y)=EVAP(Y)+C
          TLOSS(Y)=TLOSS(Y)+D
          SED_IN(Y)=SED_IN(Y)+E
          SED_OUT(Y)=SED_OUT(Y)+F
          SEDCONC(Y)=SEDCONC(Y)+G
          ORGN_IN(Y)=ORGN_IN(Y)+H
          ORGN_OUT(Y)=ORGN_OUT(Y)+I
          ORGP_IN(Y)=ORGP_IN(Y)+J
          ORGP_OUT(Y)=ORGP_OUT(Y)+K
          NO3_IN(Y)=NO3_IN(Y)+L
          NO3_OUT(Y)=NO3_OUT(Y)+M
          NH4_IN(Y)=NH4_IN(Y)+N
          NH4_OUT(Y)=NH4_OUT(Y)+O
          NO2_IN(Y)=NO2_IN(Y)+P
          NO2_OUT(Y)=NO2_OUT(Y)+Q

    END DO
END DO

DO Z=1,516
    NO3_INB(13,Z)=NO3_IN(Z)/366
    NO3_IN(Z)=0.0
  END DO


DO X=4749,5114   !2012
    DO Y=1,516
        READ(10,"(44X,17E10.3)")A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q
        FLOW_IN(Y)=FLOW_IN(Y)+A
        FLOW_OUT(Y)=FLOW_OUT(Y)+B
          EVAP(Y)=EVAP(Y)+C
          TLOSS(Y)=TLOSS(Y)+D
          SED_IN(Y)=SED_IN(Y)+E
          SED_OUT(Y)=SED_OUT(Y)+F
          SEDCONC(Y)=SEDCONC(Y)+G
          ORGN_IN(Y)=ORGN_IN(Y)+H
          ORGN_OUT(Y)=ORGN_OUT(Y)+I
          ORGP_IN(Y)=ORGP_IN(Y)+J
          ORGP_OUT(Y)=ORGP_OUT(Y)+K
          NO3_IN(Y)=NO3_IN(Y)+L
          NO3_OUT(Y)=NO3_OUT(Y)+M
          NH4_IN(Y)=NH4_IN(Y)+N
          NH4_OUT(Y)=NH4_OUT(Y)+O
          NO2_IN(Y)=NO2_IN(Y)+P
          NO2_OUT(Y)=NO2_OUT(Y)+Q

    END DO
END DO

DO Z=1,516
    NO3_INB(14,Z)=NO3_IN(Z)/366
    NO3_IN(Z)=0.0
  END DO

  DO X=5115,5481   !2013
    DO Y=1,516
        READ(10,"(44X,17E10.3)")A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q
        FLOW_IN(Y)=FLOW_IN(Y)+A
        FLOW_OUT(Y)=FLOW_OUT(Y)+B
          EVAP(Y)=EVAP(Y)+C
          TLOSS(Y)=TLOSS(Y)+D
          SED_IN(Y)=SED_IN(Y)+E
          SED_OUT(Y)=SED_OUT(Y)+F
          SEDCONC(Y)=SEDCONC(Y)+G
          ORGN_IN(Y)=ORGN_IN(Y)+H
          ORGN_OUT(Y)=ORGN_OUT(Y)+I
          ORGP_IN(Y)=ORGP_IN(Y)+J
          ORGP_OUT(Y)=ORGP_OUT(Y)+K
          NO3_IN(Y)=NO3_IN(Y)+L
          NO3_OUT(Y)=NO3_OUT(Y)+M
          NH4_IN(Y)=NH4_IN(Y)+N
          NH4_OUT(Y)=NH4_OUT(Y)+O
          NO2_IN(Y)=NO2_IN(Y)+P
          NO2_OUT(Y)=NO2_OUT(Y)+Q

    END DO
END DO

DO Z=1,516
    NO3_INB(15,Z)=NO3_IN(Z)/366
    NO3_IN(Z)=0.0
  END DO

OPEN(11,FILE='OUT',STATUS='UNKNOWN')
    DO Z=1,516
        WRITE(11,"(15(E10.3,6X))") NO3_INB(1,Z),NO3_INB(2,Z),NO3_INB(3,Z),
 $        NO3_INB(4,Z),NO3_INB(5,Z),NO3_INB(6,Z),NO3_INB(7,Z),
 $        NO3_INB(8,Z),NO3_INB(9,Z),NO3_INB(10,Z),NO3_INB(11,Z),
 $        NO3_INB(12,Z),NO3_INB(13,Z),NO3_INB(14,Z),NO3_INB(15,Z)
    END DO

CLOSE(10)
CLOSE(11)
END
```

This is part of how the 'output.sub' looks like (the file that works):

```
1
    SWAT Dec 23 2016    VER 2016/Rev 664                                                                 0/ 0/   0      0: 0: 0

    General Input/Output section (file.cio):                                        
    12/3/2018 12:00:00 AM ARCGIS-SWAT interface AV                                  



       SUB      GIS  MO DA  YR   AREAkm2  PRECIPmm SNOMELTmm     PETmm      ETmm      SWmm    PERCmm    SURQmm    GW_Qmm    WYLDmm  SYLDt/ha ORGNkg/ha ORGPkg/haNSURQkg/ha SOLPkg/ha SEDPkg/ha LAT Q(mm)LATNO3kg/hGWNO3kg/haCHOLAmic/LCBODU mg/L DOXQ mg/L TNO3kg/ha   QTILEmm TVAPkg/ha
BIGSUB   1        0  1  1 1999 .11443E+03 0.200E+00 0.000E+00 0.000E+00 0.000E+00 0.201E+03 0.000E+00 0.506E-02 0.409E-01 0.844E-01 0.714E-05 0.281E-03 0.365E-04 0.246E-03 0.232E-05 0.424E-04 0.471E-02 0.368E-03 0.180E-05 .79489E-06 0.000E+00 0.123E-01 0.000E+00 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
BIGSUB   2        0  1  1 1999 .13345E+03 0.200E+00 0.000E+00 0.000E+00 0.000E+00 0.214E+03 0.000E+00 0.466E-02 0.418E-01 0.866E-01 0.543E-05 0.247E-03 0.322E-04 0.233E-03 0.226E-05 0.370E-04 0.588E-02 0.484E-03 0.208E-05 .55263E-06 0.000E+00 0.126E-01 0.000E+00 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
BIGSUB   3        0  1  1 1999 .64204E+02 0.000E+00 0.000E+00 0.341E+00 0.169E+00 0.440E+03 0.000E+00 0.627E-03 0.150E+00 0.275E+00 0.164E-07 0.159E-04 0.209E-05 0.178E-04 0.451E-06 0.233E-05 0.952E-03 0.793E-04 0.175E-04 .45972E-10 0.000E+00 0.401E-01 0.000E+00 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
BIGSUB   4        0  1  1 1999 .43200E+00 0.000E+00 0.000E+00 0.342E+00 0.163E+00 0.550E+03 0.000E+00 0.517E-06 0.197E+00 0.348E+00 0.237E-10 0.517E-09 0.517E-09 0.517E-09 0.517E-09 0.103E-08 0.000E+00 0.000E+00 0.872E-04 .16009E-21 0.000E+00 0.507E-01 0.000E+00 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
```

And here is how the 'output.rch' file looks like:

```
1
    SWAT Dec 23 2016    VER 2016/Rev 664                                                                 0/ 0/   0      0: 0: 0

    General Input/Output section (file.cio):                                        
    12/3/2018 12:00:00 AM ARCGIS-SWAT interface AV                                  



       RCH      GIS  MO DA   YR     AREAkm2  FLOW_INcms FLOW_OUTcms     EVAPcms    TLOSScms  SED_INtons SED_OUTtons SEDCONCmg/L   ORGN_INkg  ORGN_OUTkg   ORGP_INkg  ORGP_OUTkg    NO3_INkg   NO3_OUTkg    NH4_INkg   NH4_OUTkg    NO2_INkg   NO2_OUTkg   MINP_INkg  MINP_OUTkg   CHLA_INkg  CHLA_OUTkg   CBOD_INkg  CBOD_OUTkg  DISOX_INkg DISOX_OUTkg SOLPST_INmgSOLPST_OUTmg SORPST_INmgSORPST_OUTmg  REACTPSTmg    VOLPSTmg  SETTLPSTmgRESUSP_PSTmgDIFFUSEPSTmgREACBEDPSTmg   BURYPSTmg   BED_PSTmg BACTP_OUTctBACTLP_OUTct  CMETAL#1kg  CMETAL#2kg  CMETAL#3kg     TOT Nkg     TOT Pkg NO3ConcMg/l    WTMPdegc
REACH    1        0   1  1 1999   0.1144E+03  0.1118E+00  0.1139E+00  0.0000E+00  0.1118E+00  0.8167E-01  0.8167E-01  0.8301E+01  0.3215E+01  0.2903E+01  0.9024E+00  0.7628E+00  0.7042E+01  0.7173E+01  0.0000E+00  0.2906E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.2660E-01  0.8129E-01  0.9096E-02  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.1408E+03  0.1425E+03  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.1037E+02  0.8441E+00  0.7291E+00 -0.2837E+01
REACH    2        0   1  1 1999   0.1335E+03  0.1338E+00  0.1366E+00  0.0000E+00  0.1338E+00  0.7249E-01  0.7249E-01  0.6140E+01  0.3292E+01  0.2978E+01  0.9225E+00  0.7812E+00  0.9594E+01  0.9795E+01  0.0000E+00  0.2949E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.3013E-01  0.9229E-01  0.7375E-02  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.1686E+03  0.1710E+03  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.1307E+02  0.8735E+00  0.8297E+00 -0.2837E+01
REACH    3        0   1  1 1999   0.3121E+03  0.4549E+00  0.4618E+00  0.0000E+00  0.4549E+00  0.1543E+00  0.3399E+00  0.8519E+01  0.5983E+01  0.5373E+01  0.1572E+01  0.1322E+01  0.1770E+02  0.1797E+02  0.5855E+00  0.1071E+01  0.0000E+00  0.6687E-01  0.1765E+00  0.4064E+00  0.2952E-06  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.5710E+03  0.5779E+03  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.2448E+02  0.1729E+01  0.4505E+00 -0.2837E+01
REACH    4        0   1  1 1999   0.4225E+03  0.6049E+00  0.6164E+00  0.0000E+00  0.6049E+00  0.3417E+00  0.5355E+00  0.1005E+02  0.5860E+01  0.5890E+01  0.1472E+01  0.1470E+01  0.2393E+02  0.2439E+02  0.1134E+01  0.1205E+01  0.6687E-01  0.7998E-01  0.4412E+00  0.4751E+00  0.6916E-20  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.7570E+03  0.7712E+03  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.3156E+02  0.1945E+01  0.4579E+00 -0.2837E+01
```

**UPDATED:** And this is the error I get:

```
forrtl: severe (64): input conversion error, unit 10, file C:\Users\etern\OneDrive\Documents\Indiana University\PhD Research\PhD Dissertation Writing\WabashProject\VisualStudioProjects\OutPutRCH\OutPutRCH\output.rch
Image              PC        Routine            Line        Source
libifcoremdd.dll   54013BA5  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
libifcoremdd.dll   54059BDA  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
OutPutRCH.exe      00BD1E6E  _MAIN__                    51  RCH.for
OutPutRCH.exe      00BF00D3  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
OutPutRCH.exe      00BF24DE  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
OutPutRCH.exe      00BF23C7  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
OutPutRCH.exe      00BF226D  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
OutPutRCH.exe      00BF2548  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
KERNEL32.DLL       766A8484  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
ntdll.dll          77173AB8  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
ntdll.dll          77173A88  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
```

**UPDATED:**Line 51 is this:

```
READ(10,"(44X,17E10.3)")A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q
```

The old format of the line that worked is:

```
READ(1,"(41X,9E10.3)") A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,L
```

**Here are the changes made to the code:**

1- Changed FLAGs to create new headings to match new output file.

2- Changed initial value of each flag under first Do function.

3- Changed Open function to open new output file.

4- Changed the letters used to identify variables since the new files use 17 variables, vs. 9 in the old one.

5- The Do function that represents each year of the output files was changed to match the 17 variables.

6- Changed the Read function of each year to match the new file. The data in the old file started at column number 41 of the text file, in the new one, it starts at 45. Also, data in old file are 9 characters wide, in the new one, it is 10.

7- Changed Write function to create columns with 6 characters wide vs 5 as in the old file.

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Please do *not* upload error messages as pictures, copy and paste them *as text*. It is very important. The error message must be searchable. If you do not know how to copy a text from the Windows console ask for advice. You can find it easily on the internet as well.

Comment: Also, please do do note that your code appears to be incorrectly formatted. It looks like fixed-form Fortran, but the columns at the start of the lines are all wrong. Please make sure that you copy here your code and the output a and error message **exactly** and **as text**. Also, you need to tell use which exact changes you made, you cannot expect us to caompare every line in those two source files.

Comment: What is the total number of lines in  your `output.rch`? Why are you reading 17 lines at the beginning and not 9 (as with the `sub`  file). Some other hints, compile with boundary checking, don't use usnit numbers below 10.

Comment: I thing Anas changed all instances of 9 to 17. because now 17 variables are read. However, one of the 9s was the number of lines to skip and should not have been changed...

Comment: I am trying to read 17 columns and not 17 lines, in the old code it read 9 columns. Also, I tried to change unit numbers to 10 and 11 instead of 1 and 2 but I still get the same error.

Comment: I tried to make it `DO X=1,9` to skip nine lines, but still got the same error. I will keep trying.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yes, I meant `17E10.4`. Now that I changed that the error changed from `end-of-file` to this: `forrtl: severe (64): input conversion error, unit 10, file ....` . Still in line 51 which now is: `READ(10,"(45X,17E10.4)") A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q`

Comment: Please fix the copy of your code here. This way we can't even test it if we wanted to try that to help you.

Comment: I copied the code directly from VS 2017, and also tried from the text editor, the format doesn't change here. So I uploaded the two output files and the two code files to google drive [https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ReOihiYLJgLDt68hqLC064LB8QEkU2fP?usp=sharing].
Also, @HighPerformanceMark, I tried 45X and 44X, still the same error. I believe 44X is the correct number that I should use. Not sure what the error is.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark each field is 10 characters wide, and there are 2 spaces between the fields. I just checked, and the length of each field is 10, but each field starts 2 spaces after the end of the previous field or 12 spaces from the start of the previous field. Also, can you please point where is that in my code? I mean the length of each field? Just to make sure I am following correctly.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark, Thank you for the clarification. In the previous code for `SUB` I used `E10.3` to mark nine characters, so in the new one, I used `E10.4` to mark ten. However, it doesn't work. I am not sure if it's correct, but I tried `E10.6` for field length of 12, but still get the same error.

Comment: `E10.6` specifies a field length of `10`.  If this surprises you (re-)read your Fortran documentation on the topic of `edit descriptors`.  But at this point I despair of ever finding your problem and I've lost track of what the code you are trying to fix really looks like.  I suggest you delete this question and create a [mcve] which illustrates any remaining problem but no more.

Comment: Thank you. I will take your suggestion into consideration.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark, Thank you so much. Reading more about `FORTRAN EDIT DESCRIPTORS` helped me solve the issue. The correct form of Line 51 is:
`READ(10,"(44X,17E12.3)") A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q`
I repeated that for all 14 years of the analyses and the results came out fine! I appreciate everyone's help.

Comment: Do not add  any SOLVED to the question title. You can review the [tour] to know how to use this site and how to accept  answers.

Comment: @VladimirF, Thank you for your correction. It just said I can't accept my own answers.

Comment: Of course you can, you just have to wait a day or two. I am sure it said so.

Comment: @VladimirF Thank you. I did not know that. I just did it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The was an error in the use of `Fortran Edit Descriptors`. In the original code `SUB` the read command was assaigned as `41X,E10.3`, since the data needed for the analyses started after 41 spaces, and the lenght of the `field` **including** the space before the next `field` value. In this one there was a *single* space between each `field`.
The new code `RCH` was correctly assaigned to start at `44X` but was still marked to start reading data from `E10.4` which is incorrect since the length of the `field` is actually 12; *ten numbers and two spaces* before the next `field`. The correct code is posted here for reference:

```
    PROGRAM WATER_QUALITY
IMPLICIT NONE


INTEGER X,Y,Z
INTEGER FLAGFIN(516),FLAGFOUT(516),FLAGEVAP(516),FLAGTLOSS(516),
 $  FLAGSIN(516),FLAGSOUT(516),FLAGSED(516),FLAGONIN(516),
 $  FLAGONOUT(516), FLAGPIN(516),FLAGPOUT(516),FLAGNO3IN(516),
 $  FLAGNO3OUT(516), FLAGNH4IN(516),FLAGNH4OUT(516),FLAGNO2IN(516),
 $  FLAGNO2OUT(516)
REAL A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q
REAL FLOW_IN(516),FLOW_OUT(516),EVAP(516),TLOSS(516),SED_IN(516),
 $SED_OUT(516),SEDCONC(516),ORGN_IN(516),ORGN_OUT(516),ORGP_IN(516),
 $ORGP_OUT(516),NO3_IN(516),NO3_OUT(516),NH4_IN(516),NH4_OUT(516),
 $NO2_IN(516),NO2_OUT(516)

  REAL NO3_INB(14,516)  !1999,2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012

DO X=1,516
    FLOW_IN(X)=0.0
    FLOW_OUT(X)=0.0
    EVAP(X)=0.0
    TLOSS(X)=0.0
      SED_IN(X)=0.0
      SED_OUT(X)=0.0
      SEDCONC(X)=0.0
      ORGN_IN(X)=0.0
      ORGN_OUT(X)=0.0
      ORGP_IN(X)=0.0
      ORGP_OUT(X)=0.0
      NO3_IN(X)=0.0
      NO3_OUT(X)=0.0
      NH4_IN(X)=0.0
      NH4_OUT(X)=0.0
      NO2_IN(X)=0.0
      NO2_OUT(X)=0.0
END DO



OPEN(10,FILE='output.rch',STATUS='OLD')

DO X=1,9
READ(10,*)
END DO



DO X=1,365   !1999
    DO Y=1,516
        READ(10,"(44X,17E12.3)") A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q
        FLOW_IN(Y)=FLOW_IN(Y)+A
        FLOW_OUT(Y)=FLOW_OUT(Y)+B
          EVAP(Y)=EVAP(Y)+C
          TLOSS(Y)=TLOSS(Y)+D
          SED_IN(Y)=SED_IN(Y)+E
          SED_OUT(Y)=SED_OUT(Y)+F
          SEDCONC(Y)=SEDCONC(Y)+G
          ORGN_IN(Y)=ORGN_IN(Y)+H
          ORGN_OUT(Y)=ORGN_OUT(Y)+I
          ORGP_IN(Y)=ORGP_IN(Y)+J
          ORGP_OUT(Y)=ORGP_OUT(Y)+K
          NO3_IN(Y)=NO3_IN(Y)+L
          NO3_OUT(Y)=NO3_OUT(Y)+M
          NH4_IN(Y)=NH4_IN(Y)+N
          NH4_OUT(Y)=NH4_OUT(Y)+O
          NO2_IN(Y)=NO2_IN(Y)+P
          NO2_OUT(Y)=NO2_OUT(Y)+Q
          END DO
END DO

DO Z=1,516
    NO3_INB(1,Z)=NO3_IN(Z)/365
    NO3_IN(Z)=0.0
  END DO


  DO X=366,731   !2000
    DO Y=1,516
        READ(10,"(44X,17E12.4)")A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q
        FLOW_IN(Y)=FLOW_IN(Y)+A
        FLOW_OUT(Y)=FLOW_OUT(Y)+B
          EVAP(Y)=EVAP(Y)+C
          TLOSS(Y)=TLOSS(Y)+D
          SED_IN(Y)=SED_IN(Y)+E
          SED_OUT(Y)=SED_OUT(Y)+F
          SEDCONC(Y)=SEDCONC(Y)+G
          ORGN_IN(Y)=ORGN_IN(Y)+H
          ORGN_OUT(Y)=ORGN_OUT(Y)+I
          ORGP_IN(Y)=ORGP_IN(Y)+J
          ORGP_OUT(Y)=ORGP_OUT(Y)+K
          NO3_IN(Y)=NO3_IN(Y)+L
          NO3_OUT(Y)=NO3_OUT(Y)+M
          NH4_IN(Y)=NH4_IN(Y)+N
          NH4_OUT(Y)=NH4_OUT(Y)+O
          NO2_IN(Y)=NO2_IN(Y)+P
          NO2_OUT(Y)=NO2_OUT(Y)+Q

    END DO
END DO

DO Z=1,516
    NO3_INB(2,Z)=NO3_IN(Z)/366
    NO3_IN(Z)=0.0
  END DO

  DO X=732,1096   !2001
    DO Y=1,516
        READ(10,"(44X,17E12.4)")A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q
        FLOW_IN(Y)=FLOW_IN(Y)+A
        FLOW_OUT(Y)=FLOW_OUT(Y)+B
          EVAP(Y)=EVAP(Y)+C
          TLOSS(Y)=TLOSS(Y)+D
          SED_IN(Y)=SED_IN(Y)+E
          SED_OUT(Y)=SED_OUT(Y)+F
          SEDCONC(Y)=SEDCONC(Y)+G
          ORGN_IN(Y)=ORGN_IN(Y)+H
          ORGN_OUT(Y)=ORGN_OUT(Y)+I
          ORGP_IN(Y)=ORGP_IN(Y)+J
          ORGP_OUT(Y)=ORGP_OUT(Y)+K
          NO3_IN(Y)=NO3_IN(Y)+L
          NO3_OUT(Y)=NO3_OUT(Y)+M
          NH4_IN(Y)=NH4_IN(Y)+N
          NH4_OUT(Y)=NH4_OUT(Y)+O
          NO2_IN(Y)=NO2_IN(Y)+P
          NO2_OUT(Y)=NO2_OUT(Y)+Q

    END DO
END DO

DO Z=1,516
    NO3_INB(3,Z)=NO3_IN(Z)/366
    NO3_IN(Z)=0.0
  END DO



  DO X=1097,1461   !2002
    DO Y=1,516
        READ(10,"(44X,17E12.4)")A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q
        FLOW_IN(Y)=FLOW_IN(Y)+A
        FLOW_OUT(Y)=FLOW_OUT(Y)+B
          EVAP(Y)=EVAP(Y)+C
          TLOSS(Y)=TLOSS(Y)+D
          SED_IN(Y)=SED_IN(Y)+E
          SED_OUT(Y)=SED_OUT(Y)+F
          SEDCONC(Y)=SEDCONC(Y)+G
          ORGN_IN(Y)=ORGN_IN(Y)+H
          ORGN_OUT(Y)=ORGN_OUT(Y)+I
          ORGP_IN(Y)=ORGP_IN(Y)+J
          ORGP_OUT(Y)=ORGP_OUT(Y)+K
          NO3_IN(Y)=NO3_IN(Y)+L
          NO3_OUT(Y)=NO3_OUT(Y)+M
          NH4_IN(Y)=NH4_IN(Y)+N
          NH4_OUT(Y)=NH4_OUT(Y)+O
          NO2_IN(Y)=NO2_IN(Y)+P
          NO2_OUT(Y)=NO2_OUT(Y)+Q

    END DO
END DO

DO Z=1,516
    NO3_INB(4,Z)=NO3_IN(Z)/366
    NO3_IN(Z)=0.0
  END DO



  DO X=1462,1826   !2003
    DO Y=1,516
        READ(10,"(44X,17E12.4)")A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q
        FLOW_IN(Y)=FLOW_IN(Y)+A
        FLOW_OUT(Y)=FLOW_OUT(Y)+B
          EVAP(Y)=EVAP(Y)+C
          TLOSS(Y)=TLOSS(Y)+D
          SED_IN(Y)=SED_IN(Y)+E
          SED_OUT(Y)=SED_OUT(Y)+F
          SEDCONC(Y)=SEDCONC(Y)+G
          ORGN_IN(Y)=ORGN_IN(Y)+H
          ORGN_OUT(Y)=ORGN_OUT(Y)+I
          ORGP_IN(Y)=ORGP_IN(Y)+J
          ORGP_OUT(Y)=ORGP_OUT(Y)+K
          NO3_IN(Y)=NO3_IN(Y)+L
          NO3_OUT(Y)=NO3_OUT(Y)+M
          NH4_IN(Y)=NH4_IN(Y)+N
          NH4_OUT(Y)=NH4_OUT(Y)+O
          NO2_IN(Y)=NO2_IN(Y)+P
          NO2_OUT(Y)=NO2_OUT(Y)+Q

    END DO
END DO

DO Z=1,516
    NO3_INB(5,Z)=NO3_IN(Z)/366
    NO3_IN(Z)=0.0
  END DO


  DO X=1827,2191   !2004
    DO Y=1,516
        READ(10,"(44X,17E12.4)")A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q
        FLOW_IN(Y)=FLOW_IN(Y)+A
        FLOW_OUT(Y)=FLOW_OUT(Y)+B
          EVAP(Y)=EVAP(Y)+C
          TLOSS(Y)=TLOSS(Y)+D
          SED_IN(Y)=SED_IN(Y)+E
          SED_OUT(Y)=SED_OUT(Y)+F
          SEDCONC(Y)=SEDCONC(Y)+G
          ORGN_IN(Y)=ORGN_IN(Y)+H
          ORGN_OUT(Y)=ORGN_OUT(Y)+I
          ORGP_IN(Y)=ORGP_IN(Y)+J
          ORGP_OUT(Y)=ORGP_OUT(Y)+K
          NO3_IN(Y)=NO3_IN(Y)+L
          NO3_OUT(Y)=NO3_OUT(Y)+M
          NH4_IN(Y)=NH4_IN(Y)+N
          NH4_OUT(Y)=NH4_OUT(Y)+O
          NO2_IN(Y)=NO2_IN(Y)+P
          NO2_OUT(Y)=NO2_OUT(Y)+Q

    END DO
END DO

DO Z=1,516
    NO3_INB(6,Z)=NO3_IN(Z)/366
    NO3_IN(Z)=0.0
  END DO


  DO X=2192,2556   !2005
    DO Y=1,516
        READ(10,"(44X,17E12.4)")A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q
        FLOW_IN(Y)=FLOW_IN(Y)+A
        FLOW_OUT(Y)=FLOW_OUT(Y)+B
          EVAP(Y)=EVAP(Y)+C
          TLOSS(Y)=TLOSS(Y)+D
          SED_IN(Y)=SED_IN(Y)+E
          SED_OUT(Y)=SED_OUT(Y)+F
          SEDCONC(Y)=SEDCONC(Y)+G
          ORGN_IN(Y)=ORGN_IN(Y)+H
          ORGN_OUT(Y)=ORGN_OUT(Y)+I
          ORGP_IN(Y)=ORGP_IN(Y)+J
          ORGP_OUT(Y)=ORGP_OUT(Y)+K
          NO3_IN(Y)=NO3_IN(Y)+L
          NO3_OUT(Y)=NO3_OUT(Y)+M
          NH4_IN(Y)=NH4_IN(Y)+N
          NH4_OUT(Y)=NH4_OUT(Y)+O
          NO2_IN(Y)=NO2_IN(Y)+P
          NO2_OUT(Y)=NO2_OUT(Y)+Q

    END DO
END DO

DO Z=1,516
    NO3_INB(7,Z)=NO3_IN(Z)/366
    NO3_IN(Z)=0.0
  END DO



  DO X=2557,2921   !2006
    DO Y=1,516
        READ(10,"(44X,17E12.4)")A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q
        FLOW_IN(Y)=FLOW_IN(Y)+A
        FLOW_OUT(Y)=FLOW_OUT(Y)+B
          EVAP(Y)=EVAP(Y)+C
          TLOSS(Y)=TLOSS(Y)+D
          SED_IN(Y)=SED_IN(Y)+E
          SED_OUT(Y)=SED_OUT(Y)+F
          SEDCONC(Y)=SEDCONC(Y)+G
          ORGN_IN(Y)=ORGN_IN(Y)+H
          ORGN_OUT(Y)=ORGN_OUT(Y)+I
          ORGP_IN(Y)=ORGP_IN(Y)+J
          ORGP_OUT(Y)=ORGP_OUT(Y)+K
          NO3_IN(Y)=NO3_IN(Y)+L
          NO3_OUT(Y)=NO3_OUT(Y)+M
          NH4_IN(Y)=NH4_IN(Y)+N
          NH4_OUT(Y)=NH4_OUT(Y)+O
          NO2_IN(Y)=NO2_IN(Y)+P
          NO2_OUT(Y)=NO2_OUT(Y)+Q

    END DO
END DO

DO Z=1,516
    NO3_INB(8,Z)=NO3_IN(Z)/366
    NO3_IN(Z)=0.0
  END DO


  DO X=2922,3287   !2007
    DO Y=1,516
        READ(10,"(44X,17E12.4)")A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q
        FLOW_IN(Y)=FLOW_IN(Y)+A
        FLOW_OUT(Y)=FLOW_OUT(Y)+B
          EVAP(Y)=EVAP(Y)+C
          TLOSS(Y)=TLOSS(Y)+D
          SED_IN(Y)=SED_IN(Y)+E
          SED_OUT(Y)=SED_OUT(Y)+F
          SEDCONC(Y)=SEDCONC(Y)+G
          ORGN_IN(Y)=ORGN_IN(Y)+H
          ORGN_OUT(Y)=ORGN_OUT(Y)+I
          ORGP_IN(Y)=ORGP_IN(Y)+J
          ORGP_OUT(Y)=ORGP_OUT(Y)+K
          NO3_IN(Y)=NO3_IN(Y)+L
          NO3_OUT(Y)=NO3_OUT(Y)+M
          NH4_IN(Y)=NH4_IN(Y)+N
          NH4_OUT(Y)=NH4_OUT(Y)+O
          NO2_IN(Y)=NO2_IN(Y)+P
          NO2_OUT(Y)=NO2_OUT(Y)+Q

    END DO
END DO

DO Z=1,516
    NO3_INB(9,Z)=NO3_IN(Z)/366
    NO3_IN(Z)=0.0
  END DO


DO X=3288,3653   !2008
    DO Y=1,516
        READ(10,"(44X,17E12.4)")A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q
        FLOW_IN(Y)=FLOW_IN(Y)+A
        FLOW_OUT(Y)=FLOW_OUT(Y)+B
          EVAP(Y)=EVAP(Y)+C
          TLOSS(Y)=TLOSS(Y)+D
          SED_IN(Y)=SED_IN(Y)+E
          SED_OUT(Y)=SED_OUT(Y)+F
          SEDCONC(Y)=SEDCONC(Y)+G
          ORGN_IN(Y)=ORGN_IN(Y)+H
          ORGN_OUT(Y)=ORGN_OUT(Y)+I
          ORGP_IN(Y)=ORGP_IN(Y)+J
          ORGP_OUT(Y)=ORGP_OUT(Y)+K
          NO3_IN(Y)=NO3_IN(Y)+L
          NO3_OUT(Y)=NO3_OUT(Y)+M
          NH4_IN(Y)=NH4_IN(Y)+N
          NH4_OUT(Y)=NH4_OUT(Y)+O
          NO2_IN(Y)=NO2_IN(Y)+P
          NO2_OUT(Y)=NO2_OUT(Y)+Q

    END DO
END DO

DO Z=1,516
    NO3_INB(10,Z)=NO3_IN(Z)/366
    NO3_IN(Z)=0.0
  END DO


  DO X=3654,4018   !2009
    DO Y=1,516
        READ(10,"(44X,17E12.4)")A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q
        FLOW_IN(Y)=FLOW_IN(Y)+A
        FLOW_OUT(Y)=FLOW_OUT(Y)+B
          EVAP(Y)=EVAP(Y)+C
          TLOSS(Y)=TLOSS(Y)+D
          SED_IN(Y)=SED_IN(Y)+E
          SED_OUT(Y)=SED_OUT(Y)+F
          SEDCONC(Y)=SEDCONC(Y)+G
          ORGN_IN(Y)=ORGN_IN(Y)+H
          ORGN_OUT(Y)=ORGN_OUT(Y)+I
          ORGP_IN(Y)=ORGP_IN(Y)+J
          ORGP_OUT(Y)=ORGP_OUT(Y)+K
          NO3_IN(Y)=NO3_IN(Y)+L
          NO3_OUT(Y)=NO3_OUT(Y)+M
          NH4_IN(Y)=NH4_IN(Y)+N
          NH4_OUT(Y)=NH4_OUT(Y)+O
          NO2_IN(Y)=NO2_IN(Y)+P
          NO2_OUT(Y)=NO2_OUT(Y)+Q

    END DO
END DO

DO Z=1,516
    NO3_INB(11,Z)=NO3_IN(Z)/366
    NO3_IN(Z)=0.0
  END DO


  DO X=4019,4383   !2010
    DO Y=1,516
        READ(10,"(44X,17E12.4)")A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q
        FLOW_IN(Y)=FLOW_IN(Y)+A
        FLOW_OUT(Y)=FLOW_OUT(Y)+B
          EVAP(Y)=EVAP(Y)+C
          TLOSS(Y)=TLOSS(Y)+D
          SED_IN(Y)=SED_IN(Y)+E
          SED_OUT(Y)=SED_OUT(Y)+F
          SEDCONC(Y)=SEDCONC(Y)+G
          ORGN_IN(Y)=ORGN_IN(Y)+H
          ORGN_OUT(Y)=ORGN_OUT(Y)+I
          ORGP_IN(Y)=ORGP_IN(Y)+J
          ORGP_OUT(Y)=ORGP_OUT(Y)+K
          NO3_IN(Y)=NO3_IN(Y)+L
          NO3_OUT(Y)=NO3_OUT(Y)+M
          NH4_IN(Y)=NH4_IN(Y)+N
          NH4_OUT(Y)=NH4_OUT(Y)+O
          NO2_IN(Y)=NO2_IN(Y)+P
          NO2_OUT(Y)=NO2_OUT(Y)+Q

    END DO
END DO

DO Z=1,516
    NO3_INB(12,Z)=NO3_IN(Z)/366
    NO3_IN(Z)=0.0
  END DO


  DO X=4384,4748   !2011
    DO Y=1,516
        READ(10,"(44X,17E12.4)")A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q
        FLOW_IN(Y)=FLOW_IN(Y)+A
        FLOW_OUT(Y)=FLOW_OUT(Y)+B
          EVAP(Y)=EVAP(Y)+C
          TLOSS(Y)=TLOSS(Y)+D
          SED_IN(Y)=SED_IN(Y)+E
          SED_OUT(Y)=SED_OUT(Y)+F
          SEDCONC(Y)=SEDCONC(Y)+G
          ORGN_IN(Y)=ORGN_IN(Y)+H
          ORGN_OUT(Y)=ORGN_OUT(Y)+I
          ORGP_IN(Y)=ORGP_IN(Y)+J
          ORGP_OUT(Y)=ORGP_OUT(Y)+K
          NO3_IN(Y)=NO3_IN(Y)+L
          NO3_OUT(Y)=NO3_OUT(Y)+M
          NH4_IN(Y)=NH4_IN(Y)+N
          NH4_OUT(Y)=NH4_OUT(Y)+O
          NO2_IN(Y)=NO2_IN(Y)+P
          NO2_OUT(Y)=NO2_OUT(Y)+Q

    END DO
END DO

DO Z=1,516
    NO3_INB(13,Z)=NO3_IN(Z)/366
    NO3_IN(Z)=0.0
  END DO


DO X=4749,5114   !2012
    DO Y=1,516
        READ(10,"(44X,17E12.4)")A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q
        FLOW_IN(Y)=FLOW_IN(Y)+A
        FLOW_OUT(Y)=FLOW_OUT(Y)+B
          EVAP(Y)=EVAP(Y)+C
          TLOSS(Y)=TLOSS(Y)+D
          SED_IN(Y)=SED_IN(Y)+E
          SED_OUT(Y)=SED_OUT(Y)+F
          SEDCONC(Y)=SEDCONC(Y)+G
          ORGN_IN(Y)=ORGN_IN(Y)+H
          ORGN_OUT(Y)=ORGN_OUT(Y)+I
          ORGP_IN(Y)=ORGP_IN(Y)+J
          ORGP_OUT(Y)=ORGP_OUT(Y)+K
          NO3_IN(Y)=NO3_IN(Y)+L
          NO3_OUT(Y)=NO3_OUT(Y)+M
          NH4_IN(Y)=NH4_IN(Y)+N
          NH4_OUT(Y)=NH4_OUT(Y)+O
          NO2_IN(Y)=NO2_IN(Y)+P
          NO2_OUT(Y)=NO2_OUT(Y)+Q

    END DO
END DO

DO Z=1,516
    NO3_INB(14,Z)=NO3_IN(Z)/366
    NO3_IN(Z)=0.0
  END DO


OPEN(11,FILE='OUT',STATUS='UNKNOWN')
    DO Z=1,516
        WRITE(11,"(14(E10.4,6X))") NO3_INB(1,Z),NO3_INB(2,Z),NO3_INB(3,Z),
 $        NO3_INB(4,Z),NO3_INB(5,Z),NO3_INB(6,Z),NO3_INB(7,Z),
 $        NO3_INB(8,Z),NO3_INB(9,Z),NO3_INB(10,Z),NO3_INB(11,Z),
 $        NO3_INB(12,Z),NO3_INB(13,Z),NO3_INB(14,Z)
    END DO

CLOSE(10)
CLOSE(11)
END
```